# Collect and merge data from multiple REST responses

Tags: talend

I have a project where I need to perform a REST call and collect values from the response. For each set of values collected, I need to use one value to add as a query parameter for a second REST call. Once I receive the response from the second call, I need to add that value to the set of values from the first call.

Data set A from REST call A:

[
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
},
{
"key1": "value3",
"key2": "value4"
}
]

REST Call B:

GET https://.../widgets?neededValue=value1

Data Set B:

[ {"id": "guid1", "secondaryId": "value1"} ]

Amalgam of data example:

[
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"key3" "guid1"
},...
]

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

concerning your question maybe need a bit more information specifically for the json structure you want to create.
But for this kind of use cases I usually a tFlowIterate and store the value I want to use in a global var.

So for the structure of the job I go like this :

- first rest call (and extract json values) and store the value in a globalVar (using tFlowToIterate)
- Iterate with the values in globalvar and repeat the second rest call build like this "http://test.com/widgest?neededValue=" + ((String)globalMap("KEY1")) and the globalVar is setup in the tFlowIterate component
- Extract the values from the second rest call and combine the values you want in your final json structure in a tMap (using globalVar calls) and write the json with tWriteJsonFields

[image]

It should look something like that.

I hope this answers your question